# jQuery UI calculate drag containment for big div in small div excluding border width size

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a small `<div>` element which contains a much bigger `<div>` element with a much bigger border width on all sides with opacity 0.5.

Now I have centered the bigger `<div>` in the middle of the small (parent) `<div>` and I can drag the big element from its center.

The bigger `<div>` itself is smaller than its parent but its border width (1000px) makes it much bigger than its parent.

```
<div id="small_parent">
    <div id="big_child">
    </div>
</div>
```

But I need to calculate the containment of the big child `<div>` while excluding its border width. I really need the border width to be that big so reducing the border with is not an option.

Using this does not work because the draggable element is bigger than its parent (considering its massive border).

```
$('#small_parent').draggable({
   containment:'parent'
})
```

Comment: (a) Please don't use all-capitals arbitrarily. It's considered yelling. (b) Please don't use things like `//` arbitrarily. It's distracting and serves no purpose.